# Can AOS correctly work while using display:none; in the CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I'm currently working on a school program, and what I am trying to do is `display:none` the homepage so I can create a loading screen. However, I have AOS ( animation on scroll) on my homepage and it only works when `display:none` is inactive.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

No, AOS uses CSS animations, which does not apply to elements with a hidden display. 
The work around could be to set the opacity to 0. Then animate it to 1.
or create an overlay div with a high z-index that sits above your content.

Or following AOS [documentation](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos) you could execute AOS.refresh when you want to show the body.

```
AOS.refresh();
```

will re-initialize AOS